# What is the Problem with this .includes() method?

Tags: javascript

```js
const ul1 = document.querySelector("#ul1");
const ul2 = document.querySelector("#ul2");
const tableRow1 = document.querySelectorAll("#ul1 .td");
const tableRow2 = document.querySelectorAll("#ul2 .td");

ul1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("td")) {
        e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
        if (![...tableRow1].includes(document.querySelector(".selected"))) {
            console.log('true1');
        }
    }
})

ul2.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("td")) {
        e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
        if (![...tableRow2].includes(document.querySelector(".selected"))) {
            console.log('true2');
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.selected{
  background: rgba(0, 182, 94, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul1">
    <li class="td">dsfds</li>
    <li class="td">sdfdsf</li>
    <li class="td">sdfsfs</li>
    <li class="td">sfdsfds</li>
    <li class="td">sfdssfs</li>
</ul>

<ul id="ul2">
    <li class="td">sfdss</li>
    <li class="td">sfsdfdsf</li>
    <li class="td">sfssfsf</li>
    <li class="td">sfsdsds</li>
    <li class="td">sdfsfds</li>
</ul>
```

If one is selected from first list then second list .include() method is not working, Why is this behavior? No matter how many selected in the first list, if all unchecked from second list then it should return true.

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns the first match within the entire document. You probably need to check for `ul1.querySelector(".selected")` and `ul2.querySelector(".selected")` instead. That said, I'd keep book of the current list element, store `e.target.closest('ul')` into th outer scope variable, and check against that variable, and update accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
ul1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("td")) {
        e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
        if (![...tableRow1].includes(ul1.querySelector(".selected"), 0)) {
            console.log('true1');
        }
    }
})

ul2.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("td")) {
        e.target.classList.toggle("selected");
        if (![...tableRow2].includes(ul2.querySelector(".selected"), 0)) {
            console.log('true2');
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, Just 1 question, I already write the code to search in the specific array then why it was behaving like that? As there is no connection between 1st & the second list (Array).

Comment: I saw now that the user @Teemu explained it in a comment under your question above.